# finding the inverse of a matrx

Tags: matrices, inverse, cryptography, gaussian-elimination

In order to decrypt a cipher text using hill cipher, we must first find the inverse matrix
of a given matrix.

From this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_cipher,

```
| 6  24  1  |-I      |  8 5 10  |
| 13 16  10 |     =  |  21 8 21 |
| 20 17  15 |        |  21 12 8 |
```

but from my java program , the output of the inverse after using Gauss Jordan Elimination is

```
| 6  24  1  |      |  0.159 -0.778 0.508 |
| 13 16  10 |   =  |  0.011 0.159 -0.107 |
| 20 17  15 |      | -0.024 0.857 -0.490 |
```

I don't really know why is it different and not sure which is correct. Please help.

Comment: If you're not sure which is right, just multiply it with the original matrix. If you don't get the identity matrix, it's NOT the inverse.

Comment: if I take 6 * 8, 48 = identity[0][0] and if I take 6 * 0.159, it will give me 0.954 = identity[0][0]. close to 1. so I assume that my program is correct?

Comment: I agree with @naslundx. Very clearly you can see that the first solution cannot be strictly the inverse, since you will not have one's in the diagonal with such numbers... But it could be a multiple of the inverse... Just test it!

Comment: @samlee Ho ho... You don't get the first number of the product by multiplying the first numbers each of the matrices...

Comment: @samlee That's not how to calculate the product of two matrices. Look it up (for example at Khan Academy), where you will also find how to find the inverse, for example with Jacobi's method. Neither solution is correct (although your program's is more accurate).

Comment: @samlee Note that in the wiki article, they have the inverse modulo 26, which is different than the regular inverse.

Comment: @naslundx ok I will look into it again..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must work in the integers modulo $26$, not over the reals (which is what your program seems to be doing).

To check the inverse, just do the multiplication: e.g. the inner product of the row $(6\,\,24\,\, 1)$ with the column $(8\,\,21\,\,21)$ equals $6 \times 8 + 24 \times 21 + 1 \times 21 = 573$, which modulo 26 equals 1 (as $572$ is divisible by $26$), so we get a $1$ at the left upper number of the product matrix. Similarly for the other ones.

You *can* do Gaussian elimination, but division works differently in the integers modulo $26$. (For one thing, you cannot always divide, as 26 has non-trivial divisors!) Look into working inside that ring first....